# Hyperledger build network - cannot create peer channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I'm currently following hyperledger fabric document v1.4.6 to build first network(https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/build_network.html#manually-generate-the-artifacts)

I first put the network down with ./byfn.sh down then tried creating the network.
However, when i go into docker cli and perform

```
peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
```

this creates a error saying

```
 InitCmd -> ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because cannot init crypto, folder "/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" does not exist
```

So I tried again with network up (./byfn.sh up) now with the same procedure it creates different error saying

```
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error applying config update to existing channel 'mychannel': error authorizing update: error validating ReadSet: proposed update requires that key [Group]  /Channel/Application/Org1MSP be at version 0, but it is currently at version 1
```

at the same command

First, I'm not sure whether I should be having the network up or down and second how to fix the problem.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform the manual steps, you need to start from [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/build_network.html#crypto-generator) (with any previous fabric networks down/removed) and follow all the steps in the order as listed on that page.